# Passing js variables to dynamic url -JavaScript, Django

Tags: javascript, django, url, parameters

I have this form for adding and updating data:

```
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            var url = "{% url 'api:task-create' %}"
            if(activeItem != null ){
                url = `http://localhost:8000/api/task-update/${activeItem.id}/`
                activeItem = null
            }
            var title = document.getElementById('title').value
            fetch(url, {

                method: 'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({'title':title})
            }).then(function(response){
                renderList()
                document.getElementById('form').reset()
            })
        })
```

when adding url without parameters like this `{% url 'foo:bar' %}` it works fine,

but when I do this: `{% url 'foo:bar' <any var> %}`, I am getting NoReverseMatch error.
Currently I am using static url as you can see up top inside `if` statement and it works perfectly fine.

I tried using `` ` `` to make it literal string still doesnt work.

I just want urls getting passed be dynamic.

How can I pass js variable on django dynamic url?

Comment: You should post your URL patterns, since the error you are getting is telling you that Django couldn't find any match there . Does your URLconf take any arguments? All the `url` tag does is revert the name you give it to a string in your URL patterns

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url